# How to denote an array in writing paper

Tags: algorithms, arrays, notation, didactics

How can I represent an array when I am writing to show an algorithm in writing paper. Like Pi is represented by Greek letter. We use that Greek symbol to denote the value of Pi, Kind of like a pointer.

So, is there any general symbol for representing array?

Answer (score 3):

People often use capital letters to represent arrays.  $A$ is a common choice (for the 'a' in 'array'), but by no means mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no standard. To enhance readability you should pick something that serves as a mnemonic for your readers, you might want to pick $S[\ldots]$ for something representing a string, and perhaps $P[\ldots]$ for representing a pattern, and so on... If you are dealing with a general array, then as D.W. suggests you can use $A[...]$ but unless you're writing a paper on sorting algorithms there might be something more appropriate.